# Android - alarmManager.setRepeating not repeating

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager

I´m currently trying to get my alarm manager to call a function every minute in my widget but it only calls it once. Does anyone see any problems with this code?

```
    override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {

    val alarmManager: AlarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context, UpdateService::class.java)

    if (service == null) {
        val random = (0..1000000).shuffled().first()
        service = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, random, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    }

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, service)
```

}